# Including dependencies in a Dojo build

Tags: build, dojo

Despite using the Dojo build system, my app is still including a large number of javascript files which I would have hoped to be covered by the build.

Here's my build profile:

```
var profile = (function(){
    return {
        basePath: "./",
        releaseDir: "release",
        action: "release",
        selectorEngine: "acme",
        cssOptimize: "comments.keepLines",

        packages:[{
            name: "dojo",
            location: "dojo"
        },{
            name: "dijit",
            location: "dijit"
        },{
            name: "dojox",
            location: "dojox"
        },{
            name: "my",
            location: "my"
        }],

        layers: {
            "my/admin": {
                include: ['dojo/ready', 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/query', 'dojo/request/xhr', 'my/Form', 'my/Tree/Radio']
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

The app is still including the following JS files on each request: `my/Form.js` (even though this is listed in the profile), `dojo/fx/Toggler.js`, `dijit/_base.js`, `dijit/WidgetSet.js`, `dijit/_base/focus.js`, `dijit/_base/place.js`, `dijit/place.js`, `dijit/_base/popup.js`, `dijit/popup.js`, `dijit/BackgroundIframe.js`, `dijit/_base/scroll.js`, `dijit/_base/sniff.js`, `dijit/_base/typematic.js`, `dijit/typematic.js`, `dijit/_base/wai.js`, `dijit/_base/window.js`.

`my/Tree/Radio` extends `dijit/Tree`, so I'm assuming a lot of the files above are dijit base files that are being loaded automatically by `dijit.Tree`. But surely the build tool should resolve dependencies like this and include them in the 'built' file?

I am using Dojo 1.8.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `dojo/fx`, it dynamically looks up the Toggler with the comment

```
use indirection so modules not rolled into a build
```

Not sure why, but if you add `dojo/fx/Toggler` to the `include` of your build script, it should not make the additional xhr requests.

EDIT: Apparently `dijit/Widget` does something similar with `dijit/_base`, so you will want to add that to the includes as well.

http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/14262

Comment: Thanks! Adding `dijit/_base` and `dojo/fx/Toggler` to the profile has removed all of those extra requests, so I've accepted this answer. The only one that's still getting loaded separately is `my/Form.js` (even though that's listed in the build), so if you have any thoughts on that it would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything that stands out with what you have posted.  I would look at the build log to see if there is a reason it might not include it.